# Propel ORM with column name called "deleted"

Tags: php, propel

I have a column name called "deleted" in a third party database (which I cannot change).
When I generate the object model with propel, it generates a base class with a property called "$deleted" for its own use. It then adds my "deleted" column as a property also called "$deleted".
When trying to execute a query, it complains "Cannot redeclare Base\myClass::$deleted". How can I stop propel from generating a Base object with a property which is the same name as the database column? Is there a way I can do this in the schema.xml? I tried to use the phpNamingMethod attribute but this only changes the method name, not the member variable.

This is generated by propel on every Base object:

```
 /**
     * attribute to determine whether this object has been deleted.
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $deleted = false;
```

This is generated from my schema.xml file:

```
 /**
     * The value for the deleted field.
     * @var        int
     */
    protected $deleted;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just define another phpName.

```
<column name="deleted" phpName="otherDeleteName" type="boolean" />
```

Comment: I changed the phpName to "entityDeleted" but it still calls the member variable $deleted. I think it is using the column name as the member variable.

Comment: Yes indeed. It appears it is not possible at the moment. There isn't a easy fix for that.